# How to setup One-Hot Encoding in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I have some categorical data represented with a symbol in Julia for a few different problems I want to solve which I think fits well into the form necessary for a One-Hot encoding. How can I setup and represent this data in Flux.jl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are un-familiar with the general concept of One-Hot encodings, it is worth taking some time to read about it here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/ the general gist is that in cases where you are working with non-numerical data (some category names like "cat" or "dog" rather that 0 or 1), you need a way to take the existing encoding (some string of text perhaps) and switch it to a numerical value that a machine learning model will understand.

Flux provides a [built in One-Hot Encoding function](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/data/onehot/) which can be used as follows:

```
julia> using Flux: onehot


julia> onehot(:b, [:a, :b, :c])
3-element Flux.OneHotVector{3,UInt32}:
 0
 1
 0

julia> onehot(:c, [:a, :b, :c])
3-element Flux.OneHotVector{3,UInt32}:
 0
 0
 1
```

In the first example, we assume that if we get the array:

```
3-element Flux.OneHotVector{3,UInt32}:
 0
 1
 0
```

that it is the numerical representation of the symbol `:b`. The latter example is the same but for the case of the symbol `:c`.